# IntelliJ form snapshot functionality cannot find GroupLayout layout manager

Tags: java, netbeans, intellij-idea

I am trying to import a NetBeans project consisting of a swing GUI with a few other classes. The GUI has a GroupLayout layout manager in place from NetBeans along with a .form file. I am trying to open either (not sure which or how) so that I can edit the GUI such as I did in NetBeans.

Is there are way to "inform" the snapshot function about the GroupLayout manager? 
How can I go about importing a GroupLayout based GUI into IntelliJ?

Another solution might be, is there a way to change my NetBeans GUI so that I can import it into IntelliJ easier?